# Read inputs from stdin/file and raise errors for less inputs

Tags: python

Lets say we have a simple python code like this:

```
num1 = input()
num2 = input()  
res = sum(num1,num2)
```

As per my requirements, I should be able to convert above code(that I got as some input from user) in such a way, that I should be able to supply inputs to it from a predefined file. How to do that ? And once we add that code, above works. But if we add another input like below "num3=input()", it should raise error like EOFError: EOF when reading a line. How to raise error like that ?

```
num1 = input()
num2 = input()  
num3 = input()
res = sum(num1,num2)
```

Please let me know for any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as I know there's no way to tell Pythons input function to read from anything but stdin. Without rewriting your code to use file objects, you could just redirect a file to stdin. This would send an eof at end of file and raise the error you're expecting.

For example run:

```
python script.py < file.in
```

Or if you have a shebang on the first line of the file and you've made it executable:

```
./script.py < file.in
```

This is all assuming you're running something Linux based or with a POSIX shell.

Comment: You can say `sys.stdin = open(path)` and then `input` will respond accordingly.

Comment: I never thought about assigning over sys.stdin! Although in general I'd recommend not overwriting such constants in a file. It is possible you'd later want to refer to the original constant, or if you code becomes a shared resource, other dependencies might fail!

Comment: Thanks it works. Can we do the same way for java too ? Like java abc < file.txt.

Comment: Yes, this is independent of the language. This is actually a feature of the shell you are executing the command on / the os's file managing capabilities. See here for more detail about IO Redirection: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html